# AngularFire - How to display all logged in users?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am currently building out an app using AngularFire, I love how easy it is to tap into the different Auth Providers.  I am using Twitter, Github, and I am building out an email (simple-auth) form. Using the example infrastructure provided by AnularFire I put my app together.

The issue I am having is trying to figure out a way to display all users that are logged in. I had  an empty object $scope.foo and tried to do a $scope.foo.push(user) inside of my login function, and do an ng-repeat over that. However for some reason that broke the app, Angular didn't work at all.  Anyway, for now the app is at http://chat.commublogs.com, maybe I will see you on chat there.

Comment: Can you add more information on what actually breaks when you bind $scope.foo? Console logs will be most helpful.

Comment: Actually, I was able to figure this out. I hooked into$scope.$on ("angularFireAuth:login", function(){$scope.isLoggedIn.add({newUser : $scope.user.username})}  and set a $scope.isLoggedIn = angularFireCollection(new Firebase(url2).limit(50));   Are you the "Anant" from the video I have been watching repeatedly? If so, I am about to post a new question.  I will post the link here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144032/angularfire-removing-an-object-from-an-array-with-a-twist  ~here you go Anant

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. I hooked into

```
$scope.$on("angularFireAuth:login", function(){
    $scope.loggedIn.add({newUser: $scope.user.username});
    });
```

I also set a new URL for my users so it would put them in a different collection

```
var url2 = 'https://<'yoursite'>.firebaseio.com/users';
```

And set my array to that

```
$scope.loggedIn = angularFireCollection(new Firebase(url2).limit(50));
```

The problem I am having now is removing a user from this array when they log out.  I am going to post a new question for that though.

Comment: I have changed the site where I am creating this chat it is now at http://chat.commublogs.com hope to see you there.

Comment: I think the line that might be throwing things off is :  $scope.loggedIn = angularFireCollection(new Firebase(url2).limit(50));  Basically what I see happening is upon auth we are setting $scope.user.username to currentUser and adding this currentUser to an array of users called loggedIn.  We are setting this loggedIn and passing it up to angularFireCollection