# AngularFire - Removing an object from an array, with a twist

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have modified the AngularFire chat demo quite a bit.  I am stuck at this point.  I have created an array on Firebase of users when they log in, like so...

```
var url2 = 'https://<yoursite>.firebaseio.com/users';
$scope.$on("angularFireAuth:login", function(){
    $scope.loggedIn.add({newUser: $scope.user.username});
    });
$scope.loggedIn = angularFireCollection(new Firebase(url2).limit(50));
```

and for the html...

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="x in loggedIn | unique:'newUser' ">{{x.newUser }}</li>
</ul>
```

Since each item that is repeated is not a link, and there is no button for each row of the li, (which would not be good anyway) it seems the only thing that would work is hooking into the $scope.$on("angularFireAuth:logout", function() {};  The problem I am having though is passing the specific user that is logged in through to this function so I can splice that index.

Also, since the list is being populated from Firebase it seems that splice would have to go all the way up to Firebase and remove that index.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use an object instead of an array, and the `angularFire` implicit service to do this.

Are your usernames unique? If so, you can do something like:

```js
$scope.loggedIn = {};
angularFire(new Firebase(url), $scope, 'loggedIn');
$scope.$on('angularFireAuth:login', function() {
  $scope.currentUser = $scope.user.username;
  $scope.loggedIn[$scope.currentUser] = true;
});
$scope.$on('angularFireAuth:logout', function() {
  delete $scope.loggedIn[$scope.currentUser];
});
```

Otherwise, you can use ref.push().name() to generate a unique ID for every user (and still use angularFire to bind an object):

```js
$scope.loggedIn = {};
angularFire(new Firebase(url), $scope, 'loggedIn');
$scope.$on('angularFireAuth:login', function() {
  $scope.currentUser = new Firebase(url).push().name();
  $scope.loggedIn[$scope.currentUser] = true;
});
$scope.$on('angularFireAuth:logout', function() {
  delete $scope.loggedIn[$scope.currentUser];
});
```

Comment: The issue I am having is that I am not (for some reason) using angularFire, I am using angularFireAuth and angularFireCollection.  I am using  angularFireAuth.initialize(url, {scope: $scope, name: "user"}); not sure how this all works.

Comment: So, I brought angularFire into the mix.  And using this code it appears whenever someone logs in {{loggedIn}} is an empty array while {{currentUser}} shows the currently logged in user.

Comment: {{loggedIn}} is an object not an array. Try surrounding the '$scope.loggedIn[$scope.currentUser] = true' in a $timeout block, it might be that Angular isn't picking up changes to $scope inside the auth callback.